# Force browser to download multiple script tag with same src

Tags: javascript, browser, browser-cache

I have a script tag like

```
<div id='CommentBox'></div>
<script src="http://www.mywebsite.com/widget.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

This javascript creates a comment box. (like facebook comment box)

But when users copy/paste same exact script tag more than once Chrome and IE9 does not request 2nd, 3rd file again, because it is cached. But actually people want to use comment box more than once in the same page. How can I break browser cache and force it to download as many as people pasted in their blog?

Comment: You should not have to call the script twice. Just call the function that creates the "comment box". For future reference though, what you are referring to is a cache buster. It usually consists of a generated number that will never be the same (i.e. a time stamp).

Comment: I strongly recommend you follow Frits van Campen's advice. For your particular case you do not need a cache buster. You shouldn't have to retrieve the script more than once. My apologies for the confusion but the above was just to give you an example of how to retrieve something from the server twice, such as an image, without the client caching the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing it wrong.

If you want two or more comment boxes just call the code twice. A script include is **not** like a function call.

Comment: Note depending on nature of script you may have to do some basic investigation into the script to find out what functions are actually being called (i.e. find where in the included script the appropriate function call is made), but the comment here is dead on.

Comment: I agree, but what if the code in the file writes something to the page / is automatically run upon inclusion? I don't think that's a good structure for a JS file, but still...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of Code that you write use this code:

Main HTML File:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://www.mywebsite.com/widget.js" type="text/javascript" />
</head>

<body>

  <div id="CommentBox"></div> 

   <script type="text/javascript">
     Func1();
   </script>

 </body>

</html>
```

widget.js File:

```
function FUNC1(){
   alert("Hello");
}
```